# How to create a custom module for Node-Red for use require statement of node and require npm modules inside flows

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, require, node-red

I need help to create a custom node to use the require estatement of nodeJs in node-red, according to the documentation three files are required in a common directory:

```
    require
        -required.js
        -required.html
        -package.json
```

the package.json content is:

```
     {
        "name": "node-red-contrib-require",
        "node-red": {
            "nodes": {
                "require": "required.js"
            }
        }
    }
```

the required.html content is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    RED.nodes.registerType("require", {
        category: "function",
        color: "#a6bbcf",
        defaults: {
            name: { value: "" },
        },
        inputs: 1,
        outputs: 1,
        icon: "file.png",
        label: function () {
            return this.name || "require";
        },
    });
</script>

<script type="text/html" data-template-name="require">
    <div class="form-row">
        <label for="node-input-name"
            ><i class="fa fa-tag" aria-hidden="true"></i> Module</label
        >
        <input type="text" id="node-input-name" placeholder="Name" />
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/html" data-help-name="required">
    <p>
        A simple node that implements the require statement of nodeJs to message
        payloads as required modules
    </p>
</script>
```

I don't know how to implement the code for required.js file, in NodeJs is so easy than create a
required function like:

```
function required(moduleName) {
    try {
        return moduleName ? require(moduleName) : undefined;
    } catch (error) {
        // console.log(error);
        //Node red error handle is this ok or need changes?
        node.error("error: " + error.toString(), undefined);
    }
}
```

thanks for any help, at this point I don't know if this is possible or I'm looking for pink unicorns

Comment: What do you want to do with the required module? Are you trying to work around the fact the core Function node doesn't let you require modules directly? Are you aware the Function node does let you require modules via your settings file (details in the documentation - look for `functionGlobalContext`). Have you searched on https://flows.nodered.org for any of the 3rd-party nodes that do let you do this already? Or is there something specific you need that they don't provide?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to comment, answering your questions in order:

`` What do you want to do with the required module? ''

Expose all native nodeJs modules to use as

var mod = require ("mod");

Comment: `` Are you trying to get around the fact that the main function node doesn't allow you to request modules directly? ''

After several hours of reading the documentation and after reviewing the source code of node-red the file "packages \ node_modules \ @ node-red \ nodes \ core \ function \ 10-function.js" I found that all the JS code runs in V8 virtual machine contexts using var vm = require "vm"

Comment: `` `` Do you know that the Function node allows you to request modules through its config file (details in the documentation - look for functionGlobalContext). ''

It is indeed a shame but I understand the reasons associated with this and it is explained with the answer to the previous question.

Comment: `` Have you searched flows.nodered.org for any of the third-party nodes that already allow you to do this? ''

There is no solution created as flow as collection or as node in flows.nodered.org that does this due to limitations of node "function" in node-red, I am new to this world of node-red and working on a project personal and I thought about using the simple and powerful solution that node-red offers for my project and thus be able to save some time in development

Comment: `` Or is there something specific you need that they don't provide? ''

It doesn't seem possible unless I make a custom "function" node that executes all the javascript in node Js runtime environment instead of a virtual machine, with the complications that it adds

Any good ideas about it?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @knolleary

The solution is:

[unsafe-function node for node-red](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-unsafe-function) node

[unsafe-function node for node-red](https://github.com/ozomer/node-red-contrib-unsafe-function/blob/master/unsafe-function.js) source

[forked version of node-red](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65186870/how-to-runing-scripts-and-code-strings-outside-virtual-machine-in-this-script-no/65193132#65193132) See stackoverflow answer

Answer (score 0):

You can require npm modules inside the javascript file of each node .
Your function should be this way to have the correct boolean value :

```
function required(moduleName) {
    try {
        require('https').get(`https://www.npmjs.com/package/${moduleName}`,function(response){
  return response.statusCode == 200;

})
    } catch (error) {
        // console.log(error);
        //Node red error handle is this ok or need changes?
        node.error("error: " + error.toString(), undefined);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked.