# How to Runing scripts and code strings outside virtual machine in this script Node Js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, virtual-machine, v8, node-red

The following code is part of the Node-Red core node libraries, as you can see it executes scripts in a virtual machine "vm" Node Js module.

[script on github node-red link](https://github.com/node-red/node-red/blob/master/packages/node_modules/%40node-red/nodes/core/function/10-function.js)

Any ideas on how the code should be written to execute script using the context of the Node Js environment instead of "vm" removing virtual machine usage?

Note: I am not interested in the problems related to executing insecure code, I just want it to do it outside the virtual machine to be able to use all the Node Js modules and their Globals without breaking Node-Red, because runInThisContext, get() and edit config.js is not the solution I want to remove the use of "vm".

Thanks for any idea

Comment: please, post some code that reproduce the issue at hand

Comment: @LT-Sites - as I said on your question yesterday, have you searched the flow library? https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-unsafe-function is exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: I wasted about 4 to 7 hours looking for the wrong terms instead of looking for what I want, run "unsafe function", thanks for your answer you can put it as an answer instead of a comment so I can select it as the solution to the question.

Comment: A note on terms: V8 is a virtual machine. Every JavaScript engine is "a virtual machine that executes JavaScript". In that sense, it is by definition impossible to execute JavaScript without the use of a virtual machine. What you're really asking is how to avoid using Node's `vm` module, and the reason you're interested in that is because you want to execute things _in the same context_.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @knolleary

The solution is:

[unsafe-function node for node-red](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-unsafe-function) node

[unsafe-function node for node-red](https://github.com/ozomer/node-red-contrib-unsafe-function/blob/master/unsafe-function.js) source

[forked version of node-red](https://github.com/Lt-Sites/node-blue)

changes:

- Replaced node "function" with node code "insecure function"
- The node "vm" was created with the old node "function"
- Added "text / x-red" script data help to new "function" node
- Updated the data help of the script "text / x-red" to the new node "vm"
- Added "require-from-string" dependency to node-red dependencies

[image]

Comment: It's called unsafe for a reason, replacing the shipped function node with it is not a good idea f if this is going to be used by anybody but just yourself

Comment: I agree on that which is why I included the node and its source code separate from my fork, and a clear explanation of the changes I made as well as an image capture, but at least now I am more satisfied knowing that I have a "vm" module and another "function" aka "unsafe" also included a clear description of what it does in the help text script included in the core

Comment: I am a learner, not an expert, but the next goal is to create or adapt existing code to create nodes as a node creator or node constructor and probably some changes in the client editor like making the node palette resizable and change a little the Js code associated with it so that it does not create "<br>" tags in long node names for example "websocket <br> out", if you can help and want it, you are welcome thanks for your time and your comment